# Android : Github library using in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, github, licensing

In my application I want to use github library:-https://github.com/greenfrvr/hashtag-view

I know one way to use it is by adding dependencies in gradle file as :-

```
dependencies {
compile 'com.github.greenfrvr:hashtag-view:1.2.1'
}
```

This way I am able to use library but **I want to make some changes to library code and modify according to my use.**

So my question is:-

1. Is it legal to modify github library code according to my use;
2. If yes then how to modify library code in **android studio**

This github library licence document say ---

```
The MIT License (MIT)

Copyright (c) 2015 greenfrvr

Permission is hereby granted, free of charge, to any person obtaining a copy
of this software and associated documentation files (the "Software"), to deal
in the Software without restriction, including without limitation the rights
to use, copy, modify, merge, publish, distribute, sublicense, and/or sell
copies of the Software, and to permit persons to whom the Software is
furnished to do so, subject to the following conditions:

The above copyright notice and this permission notice shall be included in all
copies or substantial portions of the Software.

THE SOFTWARE IS PROVIDED "AS IS", WITHOUT WARRANTY OF ANY KIND, EXPRESS OR
IMPLIED, INCLUDING BUT NOT LIMITED TO THE WARRANTIES OF MERCHANTABILITY,
FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE AND NONINFRINGEMENT. IN NO EVENT SHALL THE
AUTHORS OR COPYRIGHT HOLDERS BE LIABLE FOR ANY CLAIM, DAMAGES OR OTHER
LIABILITY, WHETHER IN AN ACTION OF CONTRACT, TORT OR OTHERWISE, ARISING FROM,
OUT OF OR IN CONNECTION WITH THE SOFTWARE OR THE USE OR OTHER DEALINGS IN THE
SOFTWARE.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is it legal to modify github library code according to my use;

Yes, As long as you are inline with the licence and provide proper attribution to the original author.

> If yes then how to modify library code in android studio

You cannot modify the original library if you add it as a dependency. To modify you can do one of the following:

- Fork out the repository and modify the code as you want and use in your app
- Download the code from the original repository, modify it locally and use in your code.

Comment: @AndroidMachine Thanks for your answer.

Comment: @AndroidMachine After forking the library and making changes to java file, Its asking commit changes as directly to the master branch or Create a new branch for this commit and start a pull request. What should I do. And how would I able use my this edited code in android studio

Comment: need to download that for use. forking was just so that you have a remote copy of your changes. otherwise it is same as downloading directly from original repository.

Comment: Ok can't I import it using dependencies?

Comment: One more thing, Can I publish it on jitpack (as its not my code)

Comment: depends on the licence. check with the author. if your changes are minor and generic just send a pull request from your repo. to publish separately getting consent from author would be wise.

Comment: If I download the codes zip file  do I need to change the package name of java files or there is some other way

Comment: if downloading you can use the same package name; if you go about publishing a variation you'll need a different one.